# How to ask user to join channel to start a call using Agora.io

Tags: react-native, webrtc, agora.io, videocall

I'm using [Agora.io](https://agora.io) in my react native project for video calling and I want to know when I will call tom someone and I'll join the channel but how can I' show incoming call UI in-app on the receiver mobile. So that he can also join the channel to start the call. Kindly if you have any resources let me know. Thanks

**Here is the code for initialize agro sdk**

```
init = async () => {
    const {appId} = this.state;
    this._engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
    await this._engine.enableVideo();
    this.startCall();
    this._engine.addListener('Warning', (warn) => {
      console.log('Warning', warn);
    });

    this._engine.addListener('Error', (err) => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });

    this._engine.addListener('UserJoined', (uid, elapsed) => {
      console.log('UserJoined', uid, elapsed);
      // Get current peer IDs
      const {peerIds} = this.state;
      // If new user
      if (peerIds.indexOf(uid) === -1) {
        this.setState({
          // Add peer ID to state array
          peerIds: [...peerIds, uid],
        });
      }
    });

    this._engine.addListener('UserOffline', (uid, reason) => {
      console.log('UserOffline', uid, reason);
      const {peerIds} = this.state;
      this.setState({
        // Remove peer ID from state array
        peerIds: peerIds.filter((id) => id !== uid),
      });
    });

    // If Local user joins RTC channel
    this._engine.addListener('JoinChannelSuccess', (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
      console.log('JoinChannelSuccess', channel, uid, elapsed);
      // Set state variable to true
      this.setState({
        joinSucceed: true,
      });
    });
  };
```

**Here is the code for Start Call**

```
 startCall = async () => {
    // Join Channel using null token and channel name
    await this._engine?.joinChannel(
      this.state.token,
      this.state.channelName,
      null,
      0,
    );
  };
```

how the receiver can receive the call

Answer (score 0):

Agora SDK does not have any built-in functionality for this.
A fantastic library for this would be `react-native-callkeep`.

https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep

Essentially, this library will help you draw a UI when someone tries to call you. It uses firebase push notifications to notify the callee.